# Global Array's Values Reset After Exiting Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm working on something where I assign a global array's values from a JSON object, and then use them later. Here's what I'm looking at

```
var Arr = new Array();
function parseFile() {
        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "openCSVScript.php",
           success: function(data){
              Arr = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
              Console.log(Arr[0]); //shows a proper value
           }
        });
    }
```

However, in another function this line is used:

```
console.log("Length of Arr: " + Arr.length); //displays 0
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like that function is called before the asynchronous request finished.

Comment: You should assign your JSON data to callNumArr, callNumArr = jQuery.parseJSON(data);. Then in another function just call console.log("Length of Global Arr: " + callNumArr.length)

Comment: Is the function in the same scope as this function?

Comment: @SubRed: There is no need to parse it manually. jQuery does it. He *should* use `dataType: 'json'` to ensure that this always happens though.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I just want to show that for this example it seems that the variable is not correctly assigned, not about the parsing. However my answer is not valid since he actually mistyped the example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never assign anything to `callNumArr`. So it'll *always* be empty.

Besides that, chances are good that your function is called before the asynchronous request finished. Any code that relies on `callNumArr` should be called from the `success` callback unless it's guaranteed in some other way that it won't execute before the AJAX request finished (but that's kind of unlikely, the request could e.g. take longer than expected etc).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't assigning the result to your global array. Look at the var names.